# class property conversions

Tags: python, class, properties

I have to use a `class`. I have to make sure that `x` and `y` are properties.

If the values ​​provided are not convertible to an integer, raise an `AttributeError`. If we give a value less than `0` to `x` or `y`, it is assigned the value `0`.

If we give a value greater than `10` to `x` or `y`, it is assigned the value `10`.

Here is my code:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def getx(self):
        x=int()
        return self._x
    def gety(self):
        y=int()
        return self._y

        if x>=0:
            return 0
            else if x<=10:
                return 10
```

I want to obtain this:

```
p = Point(1,12)
print(p.x, p.y) # output "1 10"
p.x = 25
p.y = -5
print(p.x, p.y) # output "10 0"
```

Comment: Please include the error you're seeing in questions to make it clearer what problem you're having, although I can see multiple in the above code snippet.  First, `self._x` and `self._y` don't exist, so those will give you AttributeErrors.  Second, there is no reason for the lines `x=int()` or `y=int()` since you never use those variables (and shouldn't be instantiating ints like that).  Third, you're returning from `gety` before it does the value check, so that won't work.   Fourth, you're never calling `getx` or `gety` in the example usage, so those functions won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks, I obtain that :                                                                        
1 12
25 -5

Comment: "If the values ​​provided are not convertible to an integer, raise an "`AttributeError` - raising `ValueError` would be more "pythonic", and consistent with the behaviour of builtins like `int()` or `float()` (`int('X')` -> `ValueError`)

Answer (score 2):

What are you looking for is `clamp()` function, which takes 3 arguments: value, desired minimal value and desired maximal value.

Properties are defined by the `@property` decorator. For testing if the value assigned to property is number I use `numbers` module. Here is sample code:

```
import numbers

def clamp(v, _min, _max):
    return max(min(v, _max), _min)

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, numbers.Number):
            raise AttributeError()
        self.__x = clamp(int(value), 0, 10)

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.__y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, numbers.Number):
            raise AttributeError()
        self.__y = clamp(int(value), 0, 10)

p = Point(1,12)
print(p.x, p.y) # output "1 10"
p.x = 25
p.y = -5
print(p.x, p.y) # output "10 0"
```